# linq to entity on dbcontext.set<>

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have multiple databases, 1 common and n company db. I use code first with one migration for common and one for the companies db.

I have a base context this is inherit to 2 contexts (common, company). I try to use only the base context and remove the specified contexts, so far no problem.

My problem is following, if i try to use linq on context.Set<> then I get an InvalidOperationException "The entity type NOCompany is not part of the model for the current context".

```
using (NOContext db = new NOContext(connection)) {
    var dbset = db.Set<NOCompany>()
        .Where(company => (company.Deleted == null) || (company.Deleted == false));

    foreach (var item in dbset) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.Matchcode);
    }
}
```

if I use this

```
using (NOContext db = new NOCommonContext(connection)) {
    var dbset = db.Set<NOCompany>()
        .Where(company => (company.Deleted == null) || (company.Deleted == false));

    foreach (var item in dbset) {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item.Matchcode);
    }
}
```

then it works fine. Where is the problem?

Following excerpt from the classes

```
public class NOContext : DbContext, INOContext
{

    public NOContext() { }
    public NOContext(string connection) : base(connection) { }

    #region - override DbContext -
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<EntityBase>()) {
            DateTime currentDateTime = DateTime.Now;

            var entity = entry.Entity;

            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added) {
                entity.CreateDate = currentDateTime;
                entity.CreateId = NOEngine.SessionInfo.CurrentUserId;
            } else if (entry.State == EntityState.Deleted) {
                entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
                entity.Deleted = true;
                entity.DeletedDate = currentDateTime;
                entity.DeletedId = NOEngine.SessionInfo.CurrentUserId;
            }
            entity.ModifiedDate = currentDateTime;
            entity.ModifiedId = NOEngine.SessionInfo.CurrentUserId;
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
    #endregion

    //database methods

}
```

Then I have 2 specified context

```
public class NOCommonContext : NOContext
{
    public const string CommonCatalog = "NOCommonDb";

    public NOCommonContext() { } 
    public NOCommonContext(string connection) : base(connection) { }

    #region - DbSets -
    public virtual DbSet<NOUser> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<NOCompany> Companies { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<NOConfig> AppConfiguration { get; set; }
    #endregion //DbSets
}
```

and

```
public partial class NOAppContext : NOContext
{

    public NOAppContext() { }
    public NOAppContext(string connection) : base(connection) { }

    #region - DbSets -
    public virtual DbSet<BPCard> BPCards { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<BPContact> BPContacts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<HRCard> HRCards { get; set; }
    #endregion //DbSets
}
```

Comment: You're instantiating a `NOContext` that doesn't define a `DbSet<NOCompany>`. It's only the derivatives of `NOContext` that are defining it. If `NOContext` is only there for the logic in `SaveChanges()` method, you better make it `abstract` and instantiate the correct (and concrete) type.

Comment: It was abstract, but I try to use this one context, and [Code]NOContext' has methods for create and check databases. Why should I write the same code many times? 'SaveChanges()' is working fine and not my problem. 
BTW: How can I mark code in comment? The

Comment: How should the base content know anything about `NOCompany`? Mind you, it doesn't even know its two subclasses. By entering a `DbSet<T>` property in a `DbContext` subclass, the `T` entity is automatically mapped to a `T` table by a number of mapping conventions. Your base class doesn't have any `DbSet`s and, hence, no mappings.

Comment: Thanks Gert, I have understand your explanation. My target was to remove the sub classes and make the base class to the only context class without mappings.

Comment: Okay, so now you understand that you'll have to enter the `DbSet`s as well?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  <br/>
BTW: How can I mark code in comment? All what I have tried was wrong :( The help of comment formatting I have read but it not works for me?